# WordPress Home Folder (Default) Issue

Tags: wordpress

I've recently relocated a WordPress site to a new host.  I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/) and things seemed to go ok.  However on the old host the installation was inside a sub-folder (news).  On the new host I want it in the public_html folder.  All files are up, I have made the appropriate changes to the wp_config file, I have edited the .htaccess file and removed any references to the old path, I have even gone into the wp_options table and made the url changes there.

However for some reason whenever I reference the index.php, it tries to point back to the old sub-folder location. I've looked in the wp-settings, wp-load files etc and for the life of me cannot find where the bad path information is.

I've gone to the wordpress.org site and several other sites, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I deleted my wp_config file and the system asked me to setup, so I did. During the setup it recognized that the database was there, etc, and sent me to the login.  I was able to login, looked at the settings, etc and they are all as they are supposed to be.

If I go directly to wp-admin or wp-login it lets me log in with no problem. however when I try to go to the site, nothing, however instead of showing the old url, it now shows a blank screen.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the SQL queries mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39497293/6049581) and see if running those help?

Comment: Frits, I gave them a try and it's still doing the same response.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all make sure that your whole database does not contain any references to the old installation otherwise some redirection may be active. For migrating your database nowadays you use the following tool to make sure that also serialized data does not contain any references to the old URL:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

2. Can you reach your backend? If only the frontend does not work its probably a permalink problem update your permalinks by going to Settings -> Permalinks -> Save (Update)
3. Check your index.php and the index.php file from the main directory and also from the subdirectory if there any redirection is active
4. Do a search (and replace) for the content of all files within your WordPress installation and check for any possible hardcoded redirection

It MUST be one of those problems.

If still no success debug your WordPress installation step-by-step (with echo "reached"; die;) to find out WHEN the redirection is happening - important points to check:

> index.php file
>
> wp-config.php file
>
> Action Hook 'init'
>
> Action Hook 'template_redirect'

This might also be helpful: http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/

Comment: I'll start working each of these, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: 1. Ran the search and replace DB tool (great tool by the way, thanks) - but no change
2. Can reach the back end directly (i.e. wp-admin and wp-login) - editing the settings - no change
3. That subfolder it wanted doesn't exist on this server - now instead of going to the folder, it just returns a blank page
4. Suggestion on a good search and replace utility to scan the files?

Thanks again for all the suggestions,

Comment: If your backend is reachable its possibly a problem with your theme. There are dozens of search and replace tools i usually use Netbeans IDE for PHP or IntelliJ IDEA. Try debugging using the hooks sequence. Also check the configuration of your webhost or write a mail to the support - there is also the possibility of server misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .htaccess file.

You probably have something that looks like this(notice the **subfolder**):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When you should actually have something that looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I updated the .htaccess earlier to get rid of the subfolder, just edited it again to be sure.  Sadly that wasn't it

Answer (score 0):

First although neither of the two posted answers solved the problem, they both were instrumental in helping me figure out what was wrong, so I voted each of them up.

Since I could log into the admin area, I knew things were pointing to the correct place. But I was still getting a blank page, well it turns out that somehow in the ftp transfer of the backup site to the server, the 'themes' folder didn't make it. Once I uploaded that folder, things are close to being back to normal.

Again, the advice I received helped me tremendously in troubleshooting this sucker.  Thanks